# Core Data - The correct way to subclass NSManagedObject in objective-c project Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data

I just get started learning how to use `Core Data` today and encountered an issue when I have to subclass from `NSManagedObject`in my objective-c project. I'm following the Stanford iOS 7 class(I come from `Swift` background and want to learn more about `objective-c`) [Stanford University Developing iOS 7 Apps: Lecture 13 - Core Data and Table View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2sZ9IjDBzs&index=13&list=PL9qPUrlLU4jSlonxFqhWKBu2c_sWY-mzg)
Here is what I've done so far:

## First

Create my `CoreDataModel.xcdatamodeld` file, and configure my entities like this

[image]

## Next

With the `CoreDataModel.xcdatamodeld` file highlighted, I go to the `Editor` and try to create `NSManagedObject` subclass

[image]

Four Swift files were created inclduing an empty bridging header file `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h`.

[image]

I have a many compiler errors:
[image]

I'm confused about why the xcode will generate `Swift` files for me instead of `objective-c` one since I have already configured using `objective-c` as my language.

How can I configure my header file to make `objective-c` recognize my `Swift` files or is there a way to create `objective-c` subclass file instead, such as `.m` and `.h` file?

The redeclaration error may come from the the codegen issue
[Xcode automatic subclass generation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017342-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7)

My drived data have the following files
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you select your model in Project navigator, in File inspector you have an option to select the language in which code will be generated:

[image: Changing language of generated model]

Answer (score 8):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989266/5620628) here already covered how to generate Swift files. Mine covers other queries in question.

> Xcode now supports automatic generation of NSManagedObject subclasses
>   in the modeling tool. The generated files are placed in DerivedData
>   and rebuilt on the first build after the model is saved. They are also
>   indexed by Xcode, so command-clicking on references and fast-opening
>   by filename works.

For more refer this [Apple Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html)

Solution for *Invalid redeclaration of NSManagedObject*:

For XCode 8.1, before you create `NSManagedObject` through Editor, select your **Entity**, go to ***Data Model Inspector*** and under ***Codegen*** select **'Manual/None'** like this:

[image]

And then create `NSManagedObject` subclass.

In case you have already created `NSManagedObject` subclass, do the following steps:

1. Go to your current **.xcdatamodeld**, set all *Entities* ***Codegen*** to **'Manual/None'**.
2. Save the project, delete Derived Data.
3. Clean & build the project.

It should work.